# SVN deletes file from my local directory when deleted from repository

Tags: svn

I want to delete a file from SVN but not from my local directory but when ever I `Delete`

a file from SVN repository it's also deleted from my local directory .

Any idea how can I avoid that ?

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html and http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you've told the repository that the file no longer exists.  If you want this file to still exist then simply back it up before updating (once you've updated past the version where the file is deleted then you're ok and won't need to do this again), then after the update just copy the file back.

The file will now show up as a new file.  If you want SVN to just ignore it from this point then set the ignore filter appropriately:

```
svn propset svn:ignore myfile .
```

Comment: Where to set this filter, I mean in which file I am using SVN client ?

Comment: This is set in the client, and it is a property of the directory.  The meaning of it is: "in this directory if a file matches this filter then don't ever show it as an unknown file"

Answer (score 0):

You have not indicated what your environment is, but in the case of Windows with the TortoiseSVN client, the TortoiseSVN Context menu provides two different ways to do this. The easier choice also happens to be the better choice typically, which is <kbd>Unversion and add to ignore list</kbd>. As the name suggests, it performs two actions that are often done together--(1) delete from the repository but keep the local copy (i.e. unversion), *and* at the same time, (2) add it to the ignore list so you are not bothered by it in the future. The second choice <kbd>Delete (keep local)</kbd> is hidden--you must hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> when opening the context menu to expose it. That does only the first action, however, which may or may not be what you want.

[image: Tortoise context menu with and without hidden choices]

*TortoiseSVN's normal context menu (left) and expanded context menu (right) with additional choices highlighted. Arrows point to the two choices addressing this question.*